# Struct allocated with malloc, why? C++ code analysis

Tags: c++, c, list, struct

The line:

```
struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Why does the new struct being instantiated involve malloc (allocating the blocks of memory for the size of the struct) ?

Also, is the re-declaration of struct redundant?

Wouldn't the following accomplish the same task?

```
Node* newNode = new Node;
```

MODE CODE BELOW:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};

//creates a new list Node
struct Node* newListNode(int data)
{
    struct Node* newNode =
            (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Because it is written in C and C doesn't know `new`, and may require `struct` all over the place.

Comment: This isn't *idiomatic* C++ but it is *legal* C++. Probably the code was written by (1) someone who knew C better than C++, or (2) by someone who wanted to use this source code in a C library as well as C++, or (3) some similar situation. **Ask the person who wrote the code if you want to know why they wrote it that way**. We're not mind readers.

Comment: this code looks like pure C to me

Comment: If it were pure C then it wouldn't (or at least shouldn't) have the casts on the result of malloc.

Comment: @Paul: Rather say "wouldn't need".  I'd argue that C code *should* be written for conformance to the C++ rules.  A C++ compiler is one of the cheapest lint tools you can get and generally quite effective at finding type safety violations which the C compiler happily accepts.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: the cast can [hide a serious problem though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (forgetting to `#include <stdlib.h>`) so it should not be used in C.

Comment: @PaulR: Even C compilers have warnings for usage of undeclared functions.  And C++-compiler-as-lint will reject it as an outright error.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There are some fundamental incompatibilities with C and C++. Just for example, the lack of the tag namespace in C++ means that the following valid C code won't compile as C++: `struct a { int x; };    struct b { int y; };  typedef struct b a;  int main() { a z; z.y = 5; }`

Comment: @dreamlax: That's legal C code, but not good code.  IMO, this is a case to say "thank you" to the C++ compiler for catching the confusing abuse of the name `a` associated with multiple structures.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Regardless, it is not always suitable to compile C as C++. Fundamental differences in semantics such as the previously mentioned tag namespace make compiling C as C++ suitable in trivial situations at best. `const` identifiers at file scope have external linkage in C, but not in C++. `sizeof('a')` produces different results, etc. etc.

Comment: @dreamlax: Indeed there are a fair number of subtle and not-so-subtle differences.  And taking advantage of any of them just makes it that much harder when you have to find a new programmer for your team, or read the code when you're tired, etc.  The only C++-incompatible features of C that I can name that add more value than any workaround are VLAs and designated initializers, and I still question whether they add enough value to justify losing the C++ type checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> Wouldn't `Node* newNode = new Node;` accomplish the same task?

No, this is not equivalent in some very important ways.  If part of the interface (contract) of this function is that it returns a pointer that can be passed to `free()`, then implementing it with `new` would violate that contract.

Additionally, the repeated redundant use of the `struct` keyword suggests that an effort has been made to ensure this code compiles correctly both as plain C and as C++.

Comment: Actually, the repeated redundant use of the struct keyword suggests an effor to ensure this code compiles correctly in a C++ compiler. C compilers cast automatically void* to any pointer type.

Comment: @oopscene: This isn't C code.  According to the question, it appears in a C++ compilation unit.